# Cannot resolve symbol 'AssetManager' in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I cannot find what import I need to add AssetManager to my application

Android Studio is not automatically adding imports

What do I need to do to make this snippet of code work?

```
    AssetManager assetManager = m_context.getAssets();
    InputStream ims = assetManager.open("helloworld.txt");
```

Comment: Add the import manually.  Look it up in the javadocs (Google for "android javadoc assetmanager") and use the full classname that the javadoc tells you.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, try to manually add the import yourself.
For me, the import was: import android.content.res.AssetManager